# TableView prints empty cells from database

Tags: java, sql, database, tableview

I have a database which i have connected to my eclipse and i am trying to get data from the database and print it in a TableView in a GUI in eclipse. I have a Controller Class which is connected to my DataAccessLayer Class which is connected to my SQLQuery Class.

When i am running the code below and press the "buttonAllKeys" in the GUI the TableView is filled with cells that are empty. However if i test the code in Eclipse and run it as a System.out.println i get all the data that i want in the console in Eclipse. My problem is that it wont show in the cells in the table view.

Anyone who might know what the issue is?

```
//In Controller Class
public void buttonAllKeys_Click(ActionEvent event) {
    try {
        ResultSet rs = dal2.allKeys();
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
            List.add(rs.getString(1));
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    tableView.setItems(List);

}


//In DataAccessLayer Class
public ResultSet allKeys() throws SQLException {
    connection = databaseConnection2(); 
    PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql2.allKeys());
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
    return rs;
}


//In SQLQuery Class
public String allKeys() {
    return "SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE xtype IN ('PK' , 'F' ) ORDER BY name";
}
```

Comment: `List` ? It is keyword. Define one `List` object and add it to the table

Comment: How do you mean? if you could give further clarification

Comment: Declare List variable before loop and add contents to the list variable and then set that variable to table

Comment: Nidheesh suggestion : 
declare this 
List<String> lst_data = new List<String>(); 
in buttonAllKeys_Click function 

and use lst_data instead of List in that function.